# pyEphem - from angle to date

Tags: pyephem

We have following function is exist

> > > j = ephem.Jupiter('1612/12/28')
> > >
> > > n = ephem.Neptune('1612/12/28')
> > >
> > > print j.ra, j.dec, j.mag

11:48:20.52 2:41:13.6 -1.96

My requirement is little different 
I would like to know date by supplying angle is it possible?

Please reply.

Thanks
Harshad

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to, given an angle, find a date. Generally, when you have a problem like this that goes “backwards” from a circumstance that you need satisfied to the determination of the date on which that happens, you will need to try one date after another over and over again until you get out the angle that you are looking for.

There are several well-known techniques for finding the time at which a function returns a given angle, which are discussed here:

[Using pyephem to calculate when a satellite crosses a Longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338324/using-pyephem-to-calculate-when-a-satellite-crosses-a-longitude/16121175)

Are you able to imagine how you might apply the ideas in that answer to your own situation, since you are also looking for a particular angle (even though it comes from a different part of PyEphem)?